# How to get CSS media attributes to work on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, cross-browser

I have written some HTML and CSS for a website, and some media queries to reformat the code when the screen shrinks. This works on browsers, when I shrink the browser window size, but isn't working on mobile devices. Can anyone think of why? See the Media CSS below:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  #education-table td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I have looked at similar issues and thus added the "screen and", but this has not fixed the issue.

Update: I am testing the code on a pixel 7. When resizing the browser to the same width as my phone it works perfectly. I have ensured my phone width is indeed below 500px. TO clarify, this code works when used on a browser where I have both emulated a pixel 5 (through dev tools on edge) as well as just resizing the browser window. However, when I load the same site on my pixel 7 (and a pixel 6a, + Samsung galaxy a30) this CSS does not kick in, and it loads the standard "desktop" CSS styling - so the columns of tables do not collapse and are impossible to read

Comment: @media also works with modern mobile browsers. However, you have to experiment a little with the max-width, which can vary from device to device.

Comment: What happens on a mobile device? Does it look zoomed out or does the CSS just not apply?

Comment: What happens if you add some JS to report on the screen size the device thinks it has? Is it under 500px?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - are you testing on a real narrow device or are you testing on a browser say emulating a narrow device? In either case, what is the device?

Answer (score 1):

This code is valid CSS and works like intended. It just applies to devices with screens smaller than 500px. I would recommend you to set the size to something higher like `768px`.

The `screen and` just ensures that the style is only applied to normal screens and not the print-view or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, your code is correct and should work on mobiles, it just depends on their screen size.

If you want to reformat your layout for mobiles in portrait orientation independently of their screen width, you might want to consider the following:

```css
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #education-table td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: This sadly did not solve my issue but is really handy to know going forward. I assume this would also apply to larger tablets in portrait mode though? So I think specifying pixel width gives you more control

Comment: Yes it would also apply to tablets but remember you can combine several conditions: `@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 500px)` for example.
You can use `min-device-pixel-ratio` but again you'll need to use it in combination of min/max width because even desktops can have bigger ratios (ie. retina screens).
Play around with your browser's dev tools and find the best combination for your case scenario ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I needed to add this line to the HTML document -->

It was not linking the device width before I added this meta tag. Thanks for the help from you all